# Switch between Run and Debug modes in Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a Python script running in PyCharm and I would like to interrupt it, examine a variable and resume. If I was using debug mode, this would be straightforward, but unfortunately I am not (and the script has been running for 24 hours). Is it possible to pause the script and then enter debug mode to examine a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. You're too late, I'm afraid.