# How to switch on debug while running in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a problem similar to this question ([Switch between Run and Debug modes in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196158/switch-between-run-and-debug-modes-in-pycharm)). I have a program running for some hours now and thought about taking a backup of some of the calculated values, but these commands are not present in the code. I am using PyCharm and if I could still activate debug mode that would be awesome, but other ways of saving these variables are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Attach to process` feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html

Comment: Thanks, I don't really need it anymore, but it is usefull information for future reference.